# Overlapping layouts using fragment transaction android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

So I am trying load my login fragment from my main activity. I think I have a problem not replacing the whole layout in when I use the fragment transcation replace() method.

Here is my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    LoginFragment lf = new LoginFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.mapView, lf);
    ft.addToBackStack("map to login");
    ft.commit();
}
```

activity_maps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_maps">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

login_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".LoginActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/Username"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/Password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/ForgotPassword"
    android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#197cff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/GoogleButton"
    android:layout_width="215dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any recommendations on how I should restructure my xml files?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any recommendations on how I should restructure my xml files?

Your problems have nothing to do with the xml layouts. First of all embedding that MapFragment in the activity layout and then replacing it with another fragment as the activity starts(onStart()) doesn't make any sense at all. Secondly, embedded fragments(meaning fragments declared in the xml with the fragment tag) can't be used in fragment transactions, they are meant to be static. So remove the MapFragment from the xml layout and do a simple transaction to add the LoginFragment in a **empty** ViewGroup from the activity layout.

Comment: Should I move all my onStart code up to onCreate, then replace the R.id.mapView with new ViewGroup() and then to switch from login to map I would remove the static fragment and then make another transcation from login_fragment to activity_maps. If I did this, what would I set setContentView to? Or should I be setting this to nothing? Sorry I am still wrapping my mind around how this is all working! Thanks for your quick response Luksprog!

Comment: @EmmettHarper *Should I move all my onStart code up to onCreate* - yes. It's not clear what are you doing with that mapfragment. Here https://gist.github.com/luksprog/4ff2963192e213d2c473 is a change to add a fragment.

Comment: The map fragment is the main part of my activity I just want to check if the user is logged in and then send them to that fragment if they're not logged in before they see the map, otherwise I will just switch the user to the map fragment. From the map fragment I plan to switch to a few more other fragment

Comment: @EmmettHarper That makes much more sense. You need to add in code the MapFragment to a container(a empty FrameLayout or a empty RelativeLayout etc) from activity_maps.xml and then in another transaction add the LoginFragment if necessary. Check this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/4ff2963192e213d2c473

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. However my MapsFragment is actually a MapsActivity. My buddy told me that I should have that as the main activity since its like the main page on the app and then make all other pages fragments. Should I move all my maps logic into a MapsFragment and just have a MainActivity for handling the navigation from fragment to fragment?

Comment: @EmmettHarper Your activity shouldn't be extending MapActivity if this is what you're doing now(because it's deprecated) it should extend the normal Activity class. Your map related code should sit in a fragment that extends MapFragment the activity should act just as a container for those fragments.

Comment: Thank you for knowledge bomb you just dropped up in here!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70604/discussion-between-emmett-harper-and-luksprog).